# VM image including ready-to-use Kerberos server?

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, kerberos

I implemented client-side Kerberos support to [an open source software](http://code.google.com/p/sardine/issues/detail?id=126), and I want to test it.

Is there a Virtual Machine image that I could quickly fire up, and that would include a properly working Kerberos environment, so that I can test my client app?

The [TurnkeyLinux Domain Controller](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller) distribution is nearly perfect and comes as a VM, but it does only domain controller, not the Kerberos part.

Comment: This is a Shopping question and thus is off topic. Aside from that, though, it's somewhat offensive to come here asking for help because you don't have the time nor skills to do X. You're developing an application. It's part of your job to know this stuff. Kerberos isn't rocket science, and it shouldn't take all that much time for you to figure it out. If anything, spin up a windows EC2 instance and kick the tires.

Comment: As I see there is an Active-directory, I am not sure it this can work but you can take a look at [turnkeylinux domain controller](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller) appliance.

Comment: @drcelus: Great idea! I am actually trying to set Ubuntu as a BIND9 primary controller (first step before I can try to install any Kerberos software), and Turnkey Domain Controller would have saved me the pain! Unfortunately there is no Turnkey Kerberos server, but it helps a lot nonetheless!

Comment: @drcelus: I included your idea into my question, as it helps understand the concept.

Comment: I finally myself created a ready-to-use Kerberos server VM, feel free to use it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/kerberos-server-vm/files/

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/are-vitual-machine-recommendations-on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Active Directory is one of the most used Kerberos implementation around, I assume you are testing against this kind of domain.

The NT Style domains provided by Samba 3 (the one in the turnkeylinux appliance) doesn't provide Kerberos authentication. You need Samba 4 to be able to build an AD style domain and have Kerberos authentication.

Since I can't seem to find any appliance with it you will have better luck downloading an evaluation version of Windows Server 2008 R2 and setting up a domain controller (which is pretty trivial).

The link for downloading Windows Server evaluation software :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-trial.aspx